# Как сделать чтобы "Пользователь_1" узнал, что "Пользователь_2" открыл сообщение?

Tags: c#, email, smtp, sendmail, mailkit

Использую:
- winform;
- Library - mailkit;
- imap.domain.net;
- smtp.domain.net;

Пробую написать приложение для Email рассылки, которое сможет реализовать "Сценарий_1".

Сценарий_1:
1. "Пользователь_1" отправляет "сообщение электронной почты_1";
2. "Пользователь_2" получает"сообщение электронной почты_1";
3. "Пользователь_2" открывает "cообщение электронной почты_1";
4. "Пользователь_1" получает сообщение о том, что "Пользователь_2" открыл "cообщение электронной почты_1";

В качестве "Пользователь_2" подразумевается адресаты из базы контактов.
Адресаты имеют различные и независимые Email клиенты.

**Вопросы**
**1.** Как сделать чтобы "Пользователь_1" узнал, что "Пользователь_2" открыл сообщение?
При этом "Пользователь_2" не должен нажимать никаких кнопок в письме (например если в письме расположить кнопку "Подтвердите прочтение" )?
**2.** Если вопрос "1" не возможно сделать, то какими другими способами можно реализовать сценарий?
Сделать кнопку в письме?
Как сделать кнопку в письме, чтобы она присылала статус о том, что письмо открыто?
**3.** Какие есть другие способы сделать "Сценарий_1"?

Comment: Если вы пишите собственный емэйл клиент, то никто вам не мешает в момент открытия письма отправлять уведомление (обратное письмо) о его прочтении/открытии.

Comment: @de_frag вы имеете ввиду, что у  "Пользователь_2"  будет мой ЕмэйлКлиент который будет отправлять уведомление? Если "да", то я в вопросе не это предполагал. У адресатов разные клиенты

Comment: Ну вы же пишите некое приложение, следовательно оно у кого-то будет. Если ваш вопрос не описывает полностью все условия, то добавьте в него все что необходимо.

Comment: @de_frag Обновил. Изменения: `Пробую написать приложение для Email рассылки, которое сможет реализовать "Сценарий_1". 
 
 В качестве "Пользователь_2" подразумевается адресаты из базы контактов.
Адресаты имеют различные и независимые Email клиенты.`  Мне удалось детализировать вопрос?

Comment: Есть такая вещь, называется [RFC 3798 (Disposition-Notification-To)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3798) - это некий заголовок письма, который отвечает как раз за уведомление указанный адрес при прочтение письма. Ставить, примерно так: [EnSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31117088/c-sharp-mailkit-read-receipt).